# Inquiry about deleting symbolic links with Files.walkFileTree

Tags: java, recursion, io

From this java tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html):

> Deleting a File or Directory
>
> You can delete files, directories or links. With symbolic links, the
>   link is deleted and not the target of the link. With directories, the
>   directory must be empty, or the deletion fails.

On the other hand from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html):

> You need to decide whether you want symbolic links to be followed. If
>   you are deleting files, for example, following symbolic links might
>   not be advisable. If you are copying a file tree, you might want to
>   allow it. By default, walkFileTree does not follow symbolic links.

They say, in the second quote, `If you are deleting files, for example, following symbolic links might not be advisable` However in the first quote it states clearly that: `You can delete files, directories or links. With symbolic links, the link is deleted and not the target of the link.`

If it's going to delete only the link and not the target, why would not be advisable following links when deleting while using `Files.walkFileTree`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with symbolic links is that you do not know where it is going to send you. So, if you delete recursively `/etc/home/Rollerball/opt`, maybe you forgot that there is a link to `/bin` that you forgot to think about.

Comment: Ok, but Files.delete(path) deletes only the link not the target.. What you say would make sense only if the "path" passed to visitFile would be already the link resolved into the target. Is it like that? if yes where can I find some docs mentioning it?

Comment: No, the issue is not with deleting `/etc/home/Rollerball/opt/link2bin`. The issue is that you are deleting recursively and follow the link, you will start traversing `/bin` and deleting the files there. Once it is deleted, then you will delete the link (you first delete the files contained in a directory and then the directory itself).

Comment: Thanks now is clearer, So as long as there are links whithin a folder before starting deliting files, if FOLLOW_LINKS is on, it will first follow all the links right?